# Nei-Gojobori - Ka/Ks - dn/ds ratio multiple implementation issues

Tags: java, algorithm, dna-sequence

Good afternoon,

I am browsing implementations of the Nei-Gojobori algorithm or the Ka/Ks ratio - the ratio between non-synonymous and synonymous codon changes.

I have found three implementation all of which claim to be the correct implementation of this algorithm.

Implementation 1 - https://github.com/adelq/dnds

Implementation 2 - https://edwards.sdsu.edu/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Vito__SRS16.pdf

Implementation 3 - my own version written based on the algorithm discussion from Introduction to Computational Genomics (Cristianini, Hahn).

Running the example in implementation 2 (Sequence1 - GTTATGAAGACC; and Sequence2 - GTACTGAAAACC;), I get the following results:

Implementation 1 - 1/6
Implementation 2 - 0.12
Implementation 3 - 0.0729751

Implementation 2 does not take into account the averaging of the synonymous and non-synonymous sites over both sequences.

Which implementation is correct? 
I wish to know which is the correct procedure so I can then scale this logic up, to allow for >2 sequences.

Thanks,
U.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.  The answer(s) to this question require application-domain knowledge not programming knowledge.

Comment: Please vote away, though I hope that there are other problem solving programmers who will avoid this level of pedantry.... I am asking about the logic of an algorithm that is used to solve a particular problem, yes. If working with an algorithm is not inclusive of your definition of programming, then feel free to vote against this question

Comment: I guess what HPM means is that without having access to the algorithm in the book you mentioned, or your implementation of it, there's not much we can do to help you.

Comment: Thats it..... this has nothing to do with my implementation, implementation 3. I want to know which of the other two I have presented 1 or 2 is the correct approach....

Comment: You may want to lower the barrier and post the two algorithms here